# how to add remotes in the GitHub app?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

I would stick using their official apps as I expect built-in functionality won't break. Yet I think I need to add a second remote to my project, see an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334769/938408) to my previous question.

How does one do that in the app? I only see a "Primary Remote Repository (origin)" box on the Settings tab of one of my repos.

Comment: `git remote add remote_url`

Comment: @majioa Thanks, but how would the app know about the new remote, then? Where will it show up. For the app, see mac.github.com or windows.github.com.

Comment: it will read **.git/config**, and will know, the above command adds the remote into the current *git* repo configuration file

Comment: Thanks again. One more thing before I try this: If the URL does not points to a nonexisting .git, will it be created? (Otherwise how do I create a remote?)

Comment: the folder **.git** always exists, it is created on `git init` or `git clone`

Comment: My bad. So first I should clone my local repo to the shared location I want to use as my secondary remote (the primary and original being GitHub)?

Comment: it you local repo isn't bare, you shell find the **.git/config** inside its folder, just fix it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46028/discussion-between-laszlo-and-majioa)