# how to use the official github apps with multiple remotes

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

I would stick to the git GUI developed and supported by GitHub people, but I cannot find how it could use multiple remotes (even though it lists the only remote associated with a local repo as the primary or original). I can add remotes from the command line (not from the app, though I asked about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21337197/938408) too), but does that mean I cannot use the app anymore?

Comment: The doco for github-for-mac specifically says that it does not support multiple remotes.   SourceTree does though :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade Thanks, I added a question about how to use SourceTree for this. If not exclusively… http://stackoverflow.com/q/21350523/938408

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation explicitly states](https://help.github.com/desktop/faq/articles/can-i-work-with-multiple-remotes/) that they don't support multiple remotes.

Although contrary to that page you can use the app with a non-Github remote, but it's still only one.