# can I use SourceTree and a GitHub app at the same time?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, atlassian-sourcetree, github-for-mac

As a novice, I prefer the simplicity of the GitHub app itself to work on our GitHub-hosted git project. However, to sync/push-and-pull another remote, I need to try SourceTree. (I am not confident enough to keep everything in the command line.)

Can I use the GitHub app for most editing of my (main) local repo and syncing with GitHub.com, and only occasionally fire up SourceTree to sync (my main local repo, as a I cannot sync the github.com remote directly to another remote, can I?) with the secondary remote? Would this work without any conflicts?

For those interested: I need the secondary remote on a shared location because it is also shared with accounts that cannot reach the internet to sync with the github.com repo directly.

Comment: Yes - they would just both operate on the same git objects and indexes from the .git store

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem to work with both apps at the same time, git repos are juste folders on your computer and both apps simply show you in a visual interface what your repos look like.

For example if you make modification on your local GitHub repo using the GitHub app and you then open this same repo with SourceTree, you'll see every pending modifications you made with the GitHub app.

There is only one index for each git repo, both apps will read the same index and show the same information. The modifications made on one side will be visible on the other side.

Hope this will help you.